# Sticky table header buggy behavior on mobile chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table, chromium, sticky

I'm trying to use `position:sticky` on my `thead th`s. On desktop it works fine, but on mobile chrome (both using Chrome Developer Tools device simulator and Chrome on my Android phone) it acts weird. (Firefox device simulator works.) Specifically:

1. When scrolling down the headers scroll with the page and don't become sticky
2. When scrolling up from the bottom, the headers don't show right away. However once you get within a certain distance from the top, the headers come into view and act sticky until you get to the top where they revert to being part of the page as expected.
3. If you start scrolling down, even while they're still in "fixed" mode (in #2), they disappear off the top with everything else like they're not fixed any more.

I've minimized my page to a pretty generic page with a table, with a `thead>tr>th` and `tbody>tr>td` structure, with enough columns to require scrolling horizontally, and the usual CSS applied to the `th`s.

Indeed, if I remove enough columns so it fits horizontally, it works.

The page is using bootstrap 3.4 but removing it doesn't seem to change the behavior.

Adding a div.table-responsive around it did not help.

Is this a bug in Chrome?

Is there any way to make it work without eliminating columns?

The full minimized example is included below and available as a codepen at https://codepen.io/nafg/pen/ErVEEK. Use codepen's "debug mode" view (available when logged in, may have to fork it) to view it standalone to reproduce (or just copy to a new .html file). (Codepen "Full Page View" and SO's "full page" option [available after running the snippet] use an iframe and do not display the issue.

Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style type="text/css">
    th {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      background: white;
    }
  </style>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="last-name"><a href="#">Last</a></th>
      <th class="first-name"><a href="#">First</a></th>
      <th class="gender"><a href="#">Gender</a></th>
      <th class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></th>
      <th class="cell"><a href="#">Cell</a></th>
      <th class="email"><a href="#">Email</a></th>
      <th class="address"><a href="#">Address</a></th>
      <th class="area"><a href="#">Area</a></th>
      <th class="city"><a href="#">City</a></th>
      <th class="state"><a href="#">State</a></th>
      <th class="zip"><a href="#">Zip</a></th>
      <th class="modified"><a href="#">Modified</a></th>
      <th class="created"><a href="#">Created</a></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9999</td><td>Smith</td><td>John</td><td>M</td><td>888-555-1212</td><td>800-555-1212</td><td>john@example.com</td><td>123 Main St.</td><td>Main</td><td>New York</td><td>NY</td><td>99999</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td>1/1/01, 12:00 AM</td><td><a href="#" class="view">View</a></td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please file a bug at crbug.com/new?

Comment: @dgrogan thanks. Filed https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=925690